# Intuitive windowpanel handling?

Tags: window-manager

I'm looking for an intuitive and easy to use windowhandling software.

**What I mean with windows:**

- software on the desktop opened in panels/terminals/windows

Target Systems:

- my primary os would be Win8
- but I'm also intrested in Win7
- and also the common and latest Linux distributions (Ubuntu/Debian/OpenSuse)

**What I want to achieve:**

Win7 and upwards already got this Snap feature, however it is limited to only either half- or fullscreen expansion.

- I'd like to 'throw' a window into a gap between other windows and it should expand into this gap
- also I noticed that Valve's Steam platform's windows kind of stick together and to the taskbar when they are close while resizing them

All this makes it more easy to deal with open windows and how to rearrange them.

Is there any software out there that would do this?
I miss this for almost a decade now..

**Solutions so far:**

- from this [question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3625/whats-a-piece-of-software-that-expands-the-snap-feature-of-windows-8-1?rq=1): [*DIVVY*](http://mizage.com/)